# Loading WAR resources during unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, war, stringtemplate

(The context is a Maven JavaEE project that is deployed as a WAR.)

My application class loads resources (using the StringTemplate 3.2.1 library) from a package in the `src/main/resources` directory. - This works like a charm, because the application class files and resources all end up in a subdirectory of `WEB-INF/classes`. The `new FileInputStream(path)` inside StringTemplate can find the resources using a simple relative path.

When testing my class using JUnit this simple setup does not work: Unit tests run from the `test-classes` directory, and the relative path then points to the wrong location (which is typically populated by resources from `src/test/resources`).

How can I pass StringTemplate a relative path that will work in both environments?

Comment: do use "mvn eclipse:eclipse" as it generates your classpath correctly as per the dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand the documentation correctly you have done something wrong using absolute path's etc instead of things which can be found on the classpath. Furthermore a resource should be loaded by using Class.getResourceAsStream("xyz.conf") where it does not matter if it's comming from src/main/resources or src/test/resources cause the classpath is the thing which matters. May be i misunderstand things.

Comment: You are absolutely right in that it is better to use the ClassLoader, but I have no control over the way StringTemplate opens resources. It simply opens a file using either a relative or absolute path.

Comment: May be it's only for release 4 but: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Using+StringTemplate+with+Java this says something different.

Comment: Yes, release 4 does a better job. However, the only ST 4 version currently available from Maven reverts to '<' and '>' delimiters while importing a ".st" file, which renders it useless for HTML templates.  :-(